# Call a method when fetching data in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I'm searching for a solution to call a method (within a model, such as before_create, after_create etc.) in Rails 4 whenever the application try to fetch datas ...

For example you have Course model and you do something like

```
   Course.first
   Course.all
   Course.where...
```

Or even through relations

```
   other_model.courses
```

I'd like to automatically call a method such as

```
   def access_courses

      binding.pry

   end
```

Which is inside the Course model. The aim of this is to simplify a lot something i'm buidling which requires a lot of linked tables ...

Is there a way to do it ? Thank you all ;)

Comment: You should be able to define an `after_find` callback in the model, as described in the linked answer.

Comment: You search better than me i think ^^ i'll try it out, because my question involve many ways to catch the call :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ActiveRecord::Callbacks documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> Lastly an `after_find` and `after_initialize` callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with `after_initialize` being triggered after new objects are instantiated as well.

So one ore both of those may be of use to you... though normally I'd say not to use these :).

Comment: Why "would you normally say not to use those"?

Comment: @Mischa because these methods are for extenuating circumstances, as the OP seems to need. Normally, using these methods for anything is overkill because of how many times they're accessed. For most cases, if you want to perform an action on finding an object it's better to just use a special method that finds the object and does that thing so you can keep the extra work to a limited subset of finds.